# Uncaught TypeError: end(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given

Tags: php

I would like to simply filter my array:

```js
$products = array(
  (object) [
    'createdAt' => "2021-12-29T14:11:47.000000Z",
    'id' => 11
  ],
  (object) [
    'createdAt' => "2021-12-29T14:11:47.000000Z",
    'id' => 22
   ],
   (object) [
     'createdAt' => "2021-12-30T09:50:42.000000Z",
     'id' => 11
   ]
);

$fun = array_filter($products, function($item){
    return $item->createdAt == end($products)->createdAt;
});

print_r($fun);
```

Why I am getting error? I can't use `end` inside `array filter`?

Error:  `Uncaught TypeError: end(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given`

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to that outer variable `$products` within your anonymous function. Make it accessible by adding `use ($products)` in the following way:

```php
$fun = array_filter($products, function($item) use ($products) {
    return $item->createdAt == end($products)->createdAt;
});
```